# ipython notebook clear all code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

All I want to do is try some new codes in ipython notebook and I don't want to save it every time as its done automatically. Instead what I want is clear all the codes of ipython notebook along with reset of variables.

I want to do some coding and clear everything and start coding another set of codes without going to new python portion and without saving the current code.

Any shortcuts will be appreciated.

Note: I want to clear every cells code one time. All I want is an interface which appears when i create new python file, but I don't want to save my current code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Jupyter, do the following to clear all cells:

1. Press `Esc` to enter command mode.
2. Hold `Shift`. Select the first and last cells to select all cells.*
3. Press `d` twice to delete all selected cells.

Alternatively, if you simply want to try out code, consider  running the `ipython` console, which is purely interactive in the REPL and does not require creating a new file.  In a command prompt, type:

```
> ipython
```

---

**Demo**

Click outside the textbox to select a cell in command mode (thanks @moondra's).

*Command Mode (Yes)*

[image]

*Edit Mode (No)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I liked the second option.

Comment: This worked for me. Just make sure when you select the cells, it should be outside of the textbox, where you type the code.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use Shift-M to merge the cells (from top) - at least there's only one left to delete manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can type dd to remove current selected cell. And if you continously press dd you can clean the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Press the scissors (cut) button multiple times for each cell you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Just do Ctrl+A , this selects all the individual blocks/cells and then press d twice.

Answer (score -3):

Ok youngster, I will break this down for ya in simple steps:

1. go to the intended textbox and put your mouse cursor there
2. on keyboard press crtl-a and delete
3. Ta-dah all done

Glad to help

Comment: It will just clear the code in the current box.I want to clear every cells code one time. All I want is an interface which appears when i create new python file, but I don't want to save my current code.